# Player is stuck when colliding with Ground in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making an arcade game using Phaser 3 and what I am trying to achieve is to collide the player with the Ground tiles. Currently my player is stuck in the top corner and I can't figure out why, there arent any errors in the console, how can I make the player collide properly without having him stuck? It seems that the issue is with the setCollisionByExclusion method

Here is my main:

```
let config = {
   type: Phaser.AUTO,
   width: 800,
   height: 500,
   physics: {
       default: 'arcade',
       arcade: {
           gravity: { y: 300 },
           debug: true
       }
   },
   scene: {
       preload: preload,
       create: create,
   },
   scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    parent: 'root',
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
},
};


new Phaser.Game(config)

function preload() {

this.load.image('sky', require('../assets/backgrounds/sky.png'));
this.load.image('jungle', require('../assets/backgrounds/jungle.png'));

this.load.image('ground', require('../assets/tiles/ground-transp.png'))
this.load.image('small-platform', require("../assets/tiles/small-platform-removebg-preview.png"))
this.load.image('jungle-platform', require("../assets/tiles/jungle-platform.png"))
this.load.image('large-platform', require("../assets/tiles/large-platform-removebg-preview.png"))
this.load.image('tree', require("../assets/backgrounds/treetrunk.png"))
this.load.image('plant', require("../assets/backgrounds/plant.png"))
this.load.image('plant2', require("../assets/backgrounds/plants2.png"))
this.load.image('rock', require("../assets/backgrounds/rock.png"))
this.load.spritesheet({
    key: 'player',
    url: require('../assets/spritesheets/dilopodo.png'),
    frameConfig: {
        frameWidth: 195,
        frameHeight: 125,
        startFrame:10,
        endFrame:3
    }
});

this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('Ground', require('../assets/maps/tutorial-level.json'));

}

function create () {

        this.bg = this.add.image(-41, -41, 'sky');
this.bg = this.add.image('jungle');
this.add.image(67, 370, 'tree')
this.add.image(167, 370, 'plant')
this.add.image(700, 350, 'plant2')
this.add.image(300, 440, 'rock')

const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'Ground' })

// Creating tilesets
const groundTileSet = map.addTilesetImage('Ground', 'ground')
const platformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('small-platform', 'small-platform')
const junglePlatformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('jungle-platform', 'jungle-platform')
const largePlatformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('large-platform', 'large-platform')

let groundLayer = map.createLayer('Ground', [groundTileSet, platformTileset, junglePlatformTileset, largePlatformTileset])
groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);



// Creating the Player

player = this.physics.add.sprite(0,0,'player');


player.setBounce(0.2);
player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);


//Physics
this.physics.add.collider(groundLayer, player )


}
```

and my map:

```
{ "compressionlevel":-1,
 "height":8,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "compression":"",
         "data":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAA==",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":8,
         "id":1,
         "name":"Ground",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":14,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }, 
        {
         "draworder":"topdown",
         "id":6,
         "name":"Tree2",
         "objects":[
                {
                 "class":"",
                 "gid":5,
                 "height":179,
                 "id":1,
                 "name":"",
                 "rotation":0,
                 "visible":true,
                 "width":86,
                 "x":9,
                 "y":452.666666666667
                }],
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"objectgroup",
         "visible":true,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextlayerid":15,
 "nextobjectid":21,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"1.9.1",
 "tileheight":64,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"..\/..\/..\/Downloads\/ground-transp.png",
         "imageheight":64,
         "imagewidth":58,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"Ground",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":64,
         "tilewidth":58
        }, 
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":2,
         "image":"..\/..\/..\/Downloads\/small-platform-removebg-preview.png",
         "imageheight":72,
         "imagewidth":153,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"small-platform",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":72,
         "tilewidth":153
        }, 
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":3,
         "image":"..\/..\/..\/Downloads\/large-platform-removebg-preview.png",
         "imageheight":54,
         "imagewidth":244,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"large-platform",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":54,
         "tilewidth":244
        }, 
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":4,
         "image":"../assets/tiles/jungle-platform.png",
         "imageheight":66,
         "imagewidth":129,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"jungle-platform",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":66,
         "tilewidth":129
        }, 
        {
         "columns":1,
         "firstgid":5,
         "image":"../assets/tiles/treetrunk.png",
         "imageheight":179,
         "imagewidth":86,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"tree2",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":1,
         "tileheight":179,
         "tilewidth":86
        }],
 "tilewidth":58,
 "type":"map",
 "version":"1.9",
 "width":14
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that in the top left corner of your map, there is a tile with the `ID` value of `4`, and since all tile id's are defined for collision, except `-1` due to this line `groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);` the player is "stuck" up there, because it is colliding.

Adding `4` to the array should solve the problem *(or removing the tile).*

***For example:*** `groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([-1, 4]);`

**Tip:** If you want to debug tilemaps, with collisions, you can use this function / code snippet below ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#renderDebug__anchor)).

```
let graphics = this.add.graphics()
groundLayer.renderDebug(graphics, {
    tileColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(0, 0, 255, 50), // Non-colliding tiles
    collidingTileColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(0, 255, 0, 100), // Colliding tiles
    faceColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(255, 0, 0, 100) // Colliding face edges
});
```

Comment: It  worked, I was wondering how to debug this, thanks

Comment: @Jordan glad it helped. I was struggling until I found this debug script a while back, that's why I wanted to share it, spread the cool hidden features. :)